# Usage of à pas: where is the negation?

Tags: expressions, négation, adverbes, littérature

In this passage from [Le Horla (Guy de Maupassant)](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Le_Horla_(recueil)/Texte_entier),
I fail to understand the usage of **à pas**:

> Tout à coup, j’ai senti qu’il était là, et une joie, une joie folle m’a saisi. Je me suis levé lentement, et j’ai marché à droite, à gauche, longtemps pour qu’il ne devinât rien ; puis j’ai ôté mes bottines et mis mes savates avec négligence ; puis j’ai fermé ma persienne de fer, **et revenant à pas tranquilles vers la porte**, j’ai fermé la porte aussi à double tour. Retournant alors vers la fenêtre, je la fixai par un cadenas, dont je mis la clef dans ma poche.

The translation I found goes like this:

> All of a sudden, I felt that he was there, and a joy, a mad joy seized me. I rose up
>   slowly and paced back and forth, for a long time, so that he wouldn’t guess anything
>   was amiss; then I took o# my shoes and nonchalantly put on my slippers; then I closed
>   the iron shutters, **and, quietly walking to the door**, closed it too with a double turn of
>   the lock. Then I came back to the window, locked it with a padlock, and put the key in
>   my pocket.

What is happening here? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no negation in this sentence.

*[Pas](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pas/1)* simply means "step" here so *revenant à pas tranquilles* means "walking back quietly" i.e. with "quiet steps".

Note that the second part of the splitted negative ***ne [pas](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pas/0)*** originally used to have this very same meaning (step) in ancient French so *je ne marche **pas*** literally means "I walk no **step**", i.e. I don't walk a step.

Similarily *je ne recule* (old French) that used to mean *je [ne] recule pas* (modern French) was often reinforced in *je ne recule pas* (old French) that we would write today: *je [ne] recule pas d'un pas*.

Comment: Dang...in Portuguese (my  native lang) step is "passo", I missed that big time!

Comment: I am not walking=Je ne marche pas. Or: I do not walk. I walk no step is not right. Anyway, it's walk back quietly, right.

Comment: @Lambie You are missing my point. "I walk no **step**" is a literal translation of the archaic underlying sentence where ***pas*** is not an adverb but a substantive just like *je ne suis **rien*** is "I am no **thing**" or *il n'y a **personne*** is "no **person** is there".

Comment: @jlliagre  You wrote: Je ne marche pas is: I walk no step. That cannot be the literal translation....I don't walk a step. But in any case, it's not really relevant here.

Comment: @jlliagre I would have to write an essay. No time and no inclination to do so. Forgive me...? :)